# Join 2 points by click on a map

Tags: javascript, dictionary

I would like to have some points defined in the map and would like to join the 2 points by clicking on them. Basically, the functionality is to identify the locations in the map and connect them by a single line. For some reason, I am not able to use google map API and would like to achieve this using JavaScript.

Comment: So you have "the map" already? If yes, tell us more info and we may be able to point you in the right direction for the  "clicking on two points" part. If no, then you're asking the wrong question.

Answer (score 2):

Javascript with use of HTML itself cannot produce a line (in any angle) between two points . But this is possible by:

- using Javascript with some vector graphics available around (SVG and VML), google maps actually use this technology to do some graphic like routing etc. [(link)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/SVG)
- HTML5 CANVAS element (with excanvas extension to get this work in IE),  [(link)](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Drawing_Graphics_with_Canvas)
- simply by "fake" lines as a html small elements position very close to each other [(link)](http://www.walterzorn.com/jsgraphics/jsgraphics_e.htm)