# Best cross-browser approaches for Javascript game graphics?

Tags: javascript, graphics

I'm wondering what the most viable approaches are for 2d game graphics, running in straight (and cross-browser) Javascript?

I've found the canvas and SVG approaches so far. Are there other straightforward methods that offer primitive graphics operations like drawing lines, circles, pixels? Preferrably supported out of the box in IE, unlike canvas/svg. :)

(I recently wrote a dinky little javascript game. Straight CSS+DOM worked for me in that case, but I'm looking into better ways of doing it next time.)

-ThomasN

Comment: <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/488437/drawing-in-map#489074"> Just read here </a> Here are more interesting resources: <a href="http://www.lutanho.net/svgvml3d/index.html">http://www.lutanho.net/svgvml3d/index.html</a> <A href="http://code.google.com/p/svg2vml/">http://code.google.com/p/svg2vml/</a>

Answer (score 2):

You can have a look at this very simple library:

http://fx.inetcat.com/

Quoting their manual:

> Compact lightweight JavaScript library
>   which extends DOM element by adding
>   animation methods. Facilitates CSS
>   properties and other parameters
>   alteration along timeline. Supports
>   parallel effects sets and effects
>   chains. Has extended set of callbacks
>   to adjust behavior.

If you follow the manual you see how easy is to make animations.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just starting my JS port of a game I'd written in Silverlight, so I haven't used it (yet), but I was really impressed by the demos and API for [Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/).

It has a great set of functions, including awesome animations.

An svg-based library lends itself well to developing with physics engines and such, in addition to being able to animate and manipulate (rotate, mirror, etc.) images/sprites.